Shall lambda automatically deduced return type be always an rvalue
Suppose that to avoid duplicated code we want to use immediately invoked lambda to chose which class member field we want to manipulate:
#include <iostream>

struct Data {
    int d;
};

class Test {
public:
    void manipData(int id, int value) {
        Data& dat = [this, id]() {
            if (id == 1) {
                return _data1;
            } else {
                return _data2;
            }
        }();
        // long, complex code
        dat.d = value;
    }
    int getData(int id) {
        const Data& dat = [this, id]() {
            if (id == 1) {
                return _data1;
            } else {
                return _data2;
            }
        }();
        return dat.d;
    }

private:
    Data _data1;
    Data _data2;
};

int main() {
    Test t;
    t.manipData(2, 69);
    std::cout << t.getData(2) << "\n";
    return 0;
}

In manipData the compiler complains that it
cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Data&' to an rvalue of type 'Data'

I guess it's because, according to lambda and Return type deduction, the lambda return type is deduced as Data (not Data&), and it returns the value by copy, producing a temporary. Easy fix would be to explicitly specify the return type  -> Data&.
However, MSVC without C++20 switch seems to accept this code, while GCC rejects it (C++20, or 17). Which compiler is right, and do I understand correctly that lambdas in this example always return copies of _dataN (hence I should consider this kind of code buggy, even if it can bind to const ref)?

Additional question: gcc seems to produce a warning if I specify explicitly a reference return type const Data& dat = [this, id]() -> Data& { for the "getter" version. Is it false positive?

This is not a [mre], there are a lot of irrelevant code. "Additional question" you ask that in another question.

On MSVC, /std:c++20 flag automatically implies /permissive-, that mean, disable compiler extensions and match the standard.
